# CSS hover off of element should trigger opposite transition

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I have a div with a "+" in it which does this on hover:

```
.removal {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  margin-left: -10px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.term:hover .removal {
  position: relative;
  left: 13px;
  opacity: 1;
  color: red;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-animation: move 0.4s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes "move" {
  from {
    left: 3px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: 13px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

The problem I'm experiencing is when I mouse off of that li, I'd like the CSS to essentially *undo* the animation found in `move`.

Any tips on how to do this? Should I add a transition to `.term` (which is the class on the `li`)?

Here's a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XueTu/1/)

Comment: i think it's better to forget about move keyframe and put them all to transition

Comment: Can you put together a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @Adrift added the fiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.removal {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  margin-left: -10px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  position:relative;
}

.term:hover .removal {
  opacity: 1;
  color: red;
  left:13px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/XueTu/8/)

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot add a comment (stupid 50 reputation points needed) I have to add an answer.

You already have "a working" solution, but ...
... your markup isn't very "ideal" especially from a semantically point of view (and even invalid, if not used with HTML5 doctype).

I would rather do it without this "CSS gimmick" in preference of a more "semantically code".
Therefore you could use pseudo elements (::before and ::after), which also could be "animated" at least for some Browsers - see: http://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/